# OPC UA .net standard reconnection

Tags: .net, opc-ua

I'm working on an opc client using the .net standard stack from the opc foundation. 
Everything seems to work as expected. I can establish a session, add subscriptions, items, get notifications when data changes...

The issue I'm having is  I can't find an event in the Session that fires when the Session is closed from the server side.

I'm testing with Kepserver EX 6. When i reinitialize or turn off the runtime in the server, my SessionClosing event isn't firing, so i supposed the Server isnt notifying the client. I don't know if it would fire after a timeout or something?

After this, my Opc.Ua.Client.Session object in the client code still shows the Connected property as true.
Only when  when i try do do something like adding a new subscription do i get a Bad session exception .

I could catch the exception and reestablish a new Session or try to fix the current one, but i'd rather know that the Session has gone bad beforehand. I don't even know if this is possible.

Thanks.

wrapped.Create

Comment: That's odd because the whole idea is to work in active way -- what session timeout do you use. How do you set keep alive event?

Answer (score 0):

This is the config. I guess i must've picked it from an example:

`var config = new ApplicationConfiguration()
            {
                ApplicationName = AppName,
                ApplicationUri = Utils.Format($@"urn:{0}:{AppName}", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()),
                ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Client,
                SecurityConfiguration = new SecurityConfiguration
                {
                    ApplicationCertificate = new CertificateIdentifier { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault", SubjectName = Utils.Format(@"CN={0}, DC={1}", "MyHomework", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()) },
                    TrustedIssuerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Certificate Authorities" },
                    TrustedPeerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Applications" },
                    RejectedCertificateStore = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\RejectedCertificates" },
                    AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates = true,
                    AddAppCertToTrustedStore = true,
                    RejectSHA1SignedCertificates = false,
                    MinimumCertificateKeySize = 1024
                },
                TransportConfigurations = new TransportConfigurationCollection(),
                TransportQuotas = new TransportQuotas { OperationTimeout = 15000 },
                ClientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration { DefaultSessionTimeout = 60000 },
                TraceConfiguration = new TraceConfiguration()
            }`

Then i use the config object in the Session constructor:

`Session.Create(config, new ConfiguredEndpoint(null, selectedEndpoint, EndpointConfiguration.Create(config)), false, "", 60000, credentials, null)`

It seems that 60000 is specified twice.